# Probability that the square of a random integer ends in 1

Tags: probability, self-study

From my intro to probability theory book:
What is the probability that a randomly selected positive integer will give a number ending in 1 if it is squared?
Hint: It is enough to consider the 1 digit numbers.
Answer: 0.2

I do not understand why we only need to consider one digit numbers. I see that 1 & 9 are the one digit numbers that produces a square ending in 1, giving a probability of 2/10 of randomly selecting them, but how can we generalize this to all positive integers?

Comment: Hint: the final digit in the product of any two integers will always equal the product of the final digit in each of the two integers - let me know in the comments if you're still having trouble and I can come back and provide a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact that answer is not sufficiently justified given the information in the question.

It depends on the distribution over the positive integers. The question says "*randomly chosen*", and the burning question is "what the heck does that mean"?

The positive integers ***can't*** all be chosen with equal probability*, so the answer therefore depends on *how* you assign probability to the original set of positive integers.

* (if they think it's possible, they're welcome to attempt to explain how one actually does that, which might be fun to watch)

Even the *Hint* doesn't pin it down.

Let's consider the 1-digit integers, and the last digit of their squares:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
 1  4  9  6  5  6  9  4  1  0
```

No doubt they're saying "well, all those last digits have an equal chance of turning up, and so the chance that a square ends in 1 is 2/10. But there's no reasonable basis on which to assert that the last digits *do* have an equal chance of turning up.

For example, if we toss a coin until we observe a head, and count the number of tosses, that will give a distribution over the integers. With that distribution, the chance is a little over 0.5:

$$p = (\frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{2})^9)(1 + (\frac{1}{2})^{10} + (\frac{1}{2})^{20} +...)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1+(\frac{1}{2})^{10}}{1 - (\frac{1}{2})^{10}}$$

Other answers are possible.

Now it's *possible* to find distributions for which 0.2 is the right answer, and it's even possible to come up with distributions for which you can immediately work it out from the above table of single digits and the knowledge of the distribution (most obviously, any distribution where the ratios on the single digits are preserved throughout the integers) - but the distributions for which it works are generally substantially less "obvious" or "natural" than say a geometric($\frac{1}{2}$) distribution, like the one I used above.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail how you got the first line of your equation? What do the exponents represent?

Comment: (+1) Although I have offered a different answer--on the premise it might indeed be "fun to watch"--there is much wisdom in this one; careful study of its points would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 6):

When a mathematician asks to pick a "random integer" or "random natural number," they usually have in mind a limiting process in which the numbers all "become equally probable."  The process can be quite general: I believe all that you need is that (a) the *relative probabilities* of any two sets should converge and (b) the relative probabilities of any two *finite* sets should converge to the ratio of their cardinalities.

One nice set of distributions with these properties is the geometric, where the chance of $k\ge 1$ is given by

$${\Pr}_x(k) = (1-x)x^{k-1}$$

for a parameter $0 \lt x \lt 1$ and values $k\in \{1,2,\ldots\}.$  The figure plots these distributions for $x=0.9, 0.99, 0.999$ and $1\le k\le 100$: as $x$ gets close to $1$, the distributions gets flatter and flatter: more and more *uniform*.

[image: Figure]

The advantage of this particular family of probability measures is that the probability of any set $A$ of positive integers, such as those whose squares end in "1", is the limiting value of

$${\Pr}_x(A) = (1-x)\sum_{k\in A} x^{k-1}$$

as $x\to 1.$  This limiting value, which appears to be the product of something going to $0$ (that is, $1-x$) and something that is growing infinitely large (the *unnormalized* chance of $A$ as given by the sum), often can easily be computed using [L'Hopital's Rule.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)  Let's illustrate with the question in hand, where

$$A=\{1,9,11,19,21,\ldots\}=\{10i+1\ |\ i \ge 0\}\cup\{10i+9\ |\ i \ge 0\} = A_1\cup A_9.$$

Because $A_1$ and $A_9$ are disjoint, this breaks the probability calculation into two parts:

$${\Pr}_x(A) = {\Pr}_x(A_1) + {\Pr}_x(A_9) = (1-x)\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{10i+1} + \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{10i+9}\right).$$

Both of these sums are geometric series with common ratios $x^{10},$ which reduces them to

$${\Pr}_x(A) = (1-x)\left(\frac{x}{1-x^{10}} + \frac{x^9}{1-x^{10}}\right) = \frac{(1-x)(x+x^9)}{1-x^{10}}.$$

Because both the numerator and the denominator of this fraction converge to $0$ as $x\to 1,$ L'Hopital's Rule says the limit can be found as the limiting ratio of the derivatives of the numerator and denominator:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}{\Pr}_x(A) = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1 - 2x + 9x^8 - 10x^9}{-10x^{9}} = \frac{-2}{-10}=\frac{2}{10}.$$

Clearly we did not just "consider only one-digit numbers" in the calculation--all the positive integers were involved--but because $A_1$ and $A_9$ are defined only in terms of the final digits ($1$ and $9$ respectively), *in that sense* we only have to be concerned about the final digits (in this particular problem).

Comment: +1 A very nice take on the question. While the limiting geometric is one of the cases where you can "work it out from the above table of single digits and the knowledge of the distribution" (as I mention in my answer), it is arguably a limiting case that would be 'natural' to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is simply as this: every number has only ten possible last digits, which is all that matters to tell if a number ends at 1. Thus, if you select a number at random, the last digit has only ten possibilities, and that's what makes your sample space: you only focus on the last digit. Every number has only ten possible last digits, all with equal probability of appearing: $\Omega=\{0,1,2,...,9\}$, for which the favorable elements for your problem are 1 and 9; thus $P = 2/10 = 0.2$.

Comment: This answer is invalid because it confuses the sample space with a random variable. The sample space is explicitly the set of "positive integers." The fact that the random variable only has ten possible values does not assure they are equally probable! As a counterexample, contemplate the similar random variable given by the last digit of $x^2+x$. Although the "last digit has ten possibilities," only three values actually arise: $0$, $2$, or $6$. What would you say their chances are: $1/10$ or $1/3$? Neither is plausible under most reasonable probability models for this question.

Comment: I'm not confusing the sample space; I just narrowed it down to ten which are the numbers that matter in the context of the problem (the last ten possible digits of any positive integer). I understand the need to try to go with a full theoretical answer, but the intuitive idea is what I just wrote.

Comment: That's exactly the confusion: the sample space does not change. The question concerns the *random variable* equal to $k^2\mod 10$ for $k\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$. It explicitly does *not* concern just the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,9,0\}$. My counterexample shows what can go wrong when you ignore this crucial distinction.

Comment: At the level I am studying, Nestor's and Colin T Bower's answers cover what I needed. The more general solutions are interesting, and I will try to understand them, but are simply beyond me at this point.

Comment: Moreover, @whuber, the sample space (I insist) is not composed by the final result of the square of the positive integer, but by the positive integers themselves, problem which I narrowed down to the last digits of them only. This is similar to the question of writing the sample space for the event :"the sum of two dice is 2". The sample space is $\Omega = \{(1,1), (1,2), ..., (6,6) \}$, and the favorable case is $(1,1)$ only. Note that in my answer I never mentioned what was the random variable, but only what the sample space (of the reduced problem, not of the original problem, I agree) was.

Comment: As for your "counterexample" the intuition is the same: again, what matters are the last digits only of all possible positive integers, whose sample space of the reduced problem (i.e., only to the last digits of the positive integers) is the same: $\Omega = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. In this case, the probability of the final digit being, e.g., 2, is $P=4/10$ (only 4 favourable cases), but for the final digit of being 1 is $P=0$. Again: I understand the need for a full theoretical answer but, in this case, the intuition is just as good if you properly transform the problem.

Comment: I was afraid you would make that objection, so I need to introduce a more complicated counterexample. What is the chance that a randomly chosen *prime* integer will end in 1? Seemingly this question, too, depends only on the last digit. The answer--$1/4$--is fairly deep; it is an instance of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions. Once again I have to insist on maintaining the crucial distinction between a sample space and the range of a random variable. By overlooking that distinction you obtained the correct answer purely by luck and intuition but not by objectively valid reasoning.

Comment: Luck? You are being a little too harsh here ;-). The way in which I solved this problem is by all means objective, rational and also intuitive, although, it is not generalizable to all problems, as it can't solve the problem you just stated. Also: i DID make the distinction between the sample space (what I used in this problem) and the random variable (which I haven't even mentioned nor on the comments or my answer).

Comment: PS: I don't think we'll make it somewhere discussing this issue because, as I can see, we are both stubborn towards the way of solving this problem (which, I accept: yours is way more elegant and generalizable, but maybe impractical for the OP's current level). I'm afraid this also has to do with our backgrounds also (maths and physics, respectively). I just want to make clear that my answer has a clear logic too (your use of 'luck' is a little offensive, I must say: my answer is not generalizable only due to the assumption of using positive integers only, and will fail if you change that).

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that some of the disagreement here could be summarized, imprecisely but maybe helpfully, as the difference "what is the probability that a random square integer ends in 1" vs "what is the probability that a random positive integer, when squared, ends in 1." I was conceiving of the problem in the second way, and I believe that is what the book meant, and why they offer 0.2 as the answer. If I'm using the word correctly, then the sample space could be reduced to the single integers in the second case but not the first.

Comment: AYD That is not the difference. Your question is about a sample space of positive integers and it concerns the random variable $X$ which assigns to any integer the last digit of its square. It asks for the probability that $X=1.$ No answer can be determined until a probability is given for the entire sample space: that is the point of @Glen_b's answer. Many errors in probability calculations originate with the unfounded assumption that when a random variable has $m$ distinct values ($m=5$ here), then all values must be equally likely. That is what Néstor assumes, without valid justification.

Comment: That is much more clear, I understand your point now. I have no way, with the information given in the question, of establishing that each possible final digit is equally likely for all positive integers. Glen_b's coin toss example is an algorithm to give a probability of selecting a given integer. Depending on how I choose to assign probability across the whole sample space, the answer will be different.

Comment: @whuber: almost a year has passed and my mind went back to this episode. After thinking a lot about it, I definetly believe that you are right and I was wrong about my solution. Your answer, BTW, is superb :).